# How to pass auth token in header using ng2 smart table (ServerDataSource)

Tags: angular, angular5, ng2-smart-table, ngx-admin

How can I pass auth token in API call to server using ng2 smart table? My current code is as below:

```
this.source = new ServerDataSource(
    http,
        {
            endPoint: environment.ApiBaseUrl + 'questions',
            dataKey: 'data',
            totalKey: 'total',
        }
);
```

I need to pass token stored in my local storage so that I can recognize the logged in user. I've found this related to this and tried it's last comment but didn't got any success [Github](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/614)

Comment: Assuming your API is setup correctly, look at Http Injector classes (intercept request and add to headers)

Comment: @AustinTFrench you are referring to the solution given in that github discussion I shared? they say it's not working..

Comment: The comments covering httpinterceptor and and the token injector yes